# How to fire the parentcontroller event inside ng-include html page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

Using ng-include i'm including a template in index.html, inside that I'm including another html page alert.html.
My issue is I can able access the scope variables of my parent controller, but I can not bind the events of my parent controller.

**index.html**

```
 <div >
      <ng-include ng-controller="MyCtrl" src="'addresform.html'" ng-init="name = 'Mike'"></ng-include>
      <ng-include ng-controller="MyCtrl" src="'addresform.html'" ng-init="name = 'byke'"></ng-include>
    </div>
```

js file.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", [ '$scope',function ($scope) {
  $scope.testVal="Sample";
  $scope.clickMe=function(name){
    alert(name);
  }
}]);
```

addresform.html

```
 Name in AddressForm 
  <ng-include src="'alert.html'"></ng-include><br>
```

alert.html

```
<input type="button" value="{{name}}" ng-click="clickMe({{name}})">
{{testVal}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/h4BF0d?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for you button should be

```
<input type="button" value="{{name}}" ng-click="clickMe(name)">
```

You don't need to interpolate `name` var with `{{}}`, because inside `ng-click="clickMe(name)"` it's already an expression.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/DttOq8Jgj6WoMhd8TkCa?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer..your solution is working fine for this. But in my real application..I have included outpt.html in index.html  using ng-include, in outpt.html I have included one more alert.html inside one div, where as this alert.html is hidden by default.(Besides I'm overwriting the window.alert method for my custom UI in alert dialogue) When i click button on outpt.html I'm sending whole alert.html parent div html with jquery to my custom alert(msg(ex:html content),title) method. In this case I'm not able to fire the events from alert. Please suggest me what could be the prblm.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you create separate question and describe your issue in details?

Comment: Please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669939/angular-controller-event-is-not-firing-on-custom-alert