# angular Controller event is not firing on custom alert

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

My Problem is Click event is not firing from alert.html.

In index.html I have included output.html assigned to outputController, in output.html I have included alert.html by default alert.html will be hidden.

When I click on a button from output.html it will fire openWindow() method, inside it will call javascript alert method. (Where as we have overwritten the window.alert method to change the view of normal basic alert.) I can able to get the view in alert dialogue and even I can able to access the $scope member variable in alert.html but my problem is I can not fire click event. anyone suggest me what could be the problem with my code.

**OutputController.js**

```
  App.controller('OutputController',[ '$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.testVal = "Ajith";
        $scope.checkClick = function () {
            console.log("Clicked");
        };
 $scope.openWindow = function (title) {
        alert(angular.element(document.querySelector("#HtmlA"))).html(), title);
       };
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
 <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_4"  ng-controller="OutputController">
            <div class="outputTab" ng-include src="'views/output.html'"></div>
        </div>
```

**output.html**

```
 <input type="button"  ng-click="openWindow('A')" value="OenAlert"/>
        <div id="HtmlA" ng-controller="OutputController" ng-init="Type = 'A'"
             ng-include="'views/alert.html'" ng-hide="true"></div>
```

**alert.html**

```
    {{testVal}}
<input type="button" ng-click="checkClick()" value="Click Here"/>
```

Comment: does you alert html code comes under the div having ng-controller?

Comment: I did not mention controller seperately on alert.html code but I think when you include inside the controller all included html files can access the controller scope.

Comment: There is an issue with angular regarding combination of ng-include and ng-controller. 

It is addressed here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4431

so you should avoid using them together as of now until its fixed.

Comment: Not sure, looks like it work http://plnkr.co/edit/ERGYkRZd06R9LhgYOVYp?p=preview ?

Comment: @dfsq I can able to get the event from output.html but I can not fire the event from my customized alert view. where I poping an alert dialogue with custom html.

Comment: What is customized alert view? Can you adjust my plunkr to demonstrate it?

Comment: Please check this. http://plnkr.co/edit/FEtJo3?p=preview

Comment: you cannot catch the element with all the events binded to it. you will need $compile service to bind the events before assigning it. That is why the events are not firing.

Comment: @Kop4Lyf can you please update http://plnkr.co/edit/FEtJo3?p=preview with binding the events.

Comment: I tried that but it seems difficult for me as the alert method is outside the scope of angular. If you create the alert method in angular way, that might solve the problem.

Comment: When I use custom alert method, if it is in outside of the scope of angular, then how my scope variable is printing on alert.html on alert dialogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per above suggestions I have removed my `custom alert`, I have used `angular-ui modal popup`. It was working fine.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FEtJo3?p=preview